# Callback для завершения анимации

Tags: android, анимация, kotlin, callback

Есть класс helper в котором в зависимости от state я добавляю анимацию(меняю прозрачность для view) после чего присваиваю View состояние VISIBLE/GONE. 
Суть в том, что на данный момент я проставляю анимации конкретное значение `duration`, после чего в Handler'e проставляю это же самое значение.

```
fun CustomButton.updateState(showActionVisibility: Boolean) {
if (showActionVisibility) {
    val animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "alpha", 1f)
    animation.duration = resources?.getInteger(R.integer.action_button_animation_time)?.toLong() ?: 0
    animation.start()
    showActionButton()
} else {
    val animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "alpha", 0f)
    animation.duration = resources?.getInteger(R.integer.action_button_animation_time)?.toLong() ?: 0
    animation.start()
    hideActionButton()
}
}

fun CustomButton.hideActionButton() {
    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed({
        visibility = View.GONE
    }, resources?.getInteger(R.integer.action_button_animation_time)?.toLong() ?: 0)
}

fun CustomButton.showActionButton() {
    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed({
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }, resources?.getInteger(R.integer.action_button_animation_time)?.toLong() ?: 0)
}
```

В принципе работает более менее удовлетворительно, НО бывают такие моменты когда после старта анимации, она попадает в очередь и duration тем самым может увеличиться. Поэтому хотелось бы вместо Handler'a использовать callback который будет говорить что анимация завершена. Вот собственно и проблема в его написании.

Answer (score 1):

```
        animationName.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {
        }
    })
```

onAnimationEnd не решит вопрос?